# Callback function won't work, even though data is being added correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a chrome extension and doing (what I thought was) a simple username registration. The username is being entered into the database through the api no problem, but the callback function with an alert for the user isn't firing.

I am new to node and express so I think this might be a asynch problem I don't understand. I appreciate any direction you can give me:

```
var uName = document.getElementById("tryUsername").value;

// adds username to the local chrome.storage
chrome.storage.local.set({'username': uName}, function (result) {
chrome.storage.local.get('username', function (result) {

        // creates new object in the database with this username 
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert("username registered!");
              window.close();   
          } 
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "https://website.com/new/" + result.username, true);
        xhttp.send();        

   });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that extensions actually allow you to use `alert()`?

Comment: I have used them before and they do work as expected. The window.close also isn't doing anything in the callback, so I think the callback isn't working at all

Comment: Have you checked the network tab to see if the request is being initiated? Or if there are any errors in the developer console?

Comment: I'd be curious if `this` is actually what you think it is.  I'd console.log it to verify.  If it isn't, you should be able to just do `xhttp.readyState`

Comment: I think you're right, I removed the this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 and now the alert is popping up. Thank you for your help, I will continue to look at this so I understand what is going on.